# Why do we need functions with compact support?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

My question is simply, why do we need functions with compact support? Are they a ntaural consequence of including Urysohn's lemma or Tietze extension theorem-which implies the Urysohn's lemma-?

I just want to understand where do they come from so the theorems including them will be more familiar to me.

Comment: They are the key for partition of unity which are really useful for lot of constructions in differential geometry.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean 'why do they exist?' or 'what do we use them for?'  For an example of the latter [distribution theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) comes to mind.

Comment: The partition of unity includes functions called "bump functions" and they are compactly supported. I just heard that but do not know how to construct these functions or why they have compact support either.

Comment: @DMcMor, I mean -mostly- "what do we use them for"

Comment: You can read the proof of existence of partition of unity in any book of differential geometry/introduction to manifold, e.g the book of John Lee "Introduction to smooth manifolds".

Comment: @N.H., I would like to mention that I am mostly interested in their usage in point set topology.

Comment: Ninja : well they are not very intersecting if you are just interested in point-set topology.

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Riesz(–Markov–Kakutani) representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)?

Answer (score 1):

Functions with compact support are of great use, e.g. since the following theorem holds:

> **Theorem** Let $(\Omega, \mu)$ be a measurable space, such that $\Omega$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ is a tight Borel measure. If $\nu$ is another such measure on $\Omega$ which gives the same integral on compactly supported continuous functions, then $\mu = \nu$.

This theorem paves the way for proving e.g. the existence of Haar measure on compact Hausdorff groups by the way of using oscillation.

Comment: If we only consider point set topology only, what changes if we have a compact support, or in general, a compact subset of the domain? I know that the images of compact (sub)spaces are compact, so?

Comment: Tightness means that for a measurable (eg. open) $E \subset \Omega$ we can give an ascending sequence of compacts $K_1 \subseteq K_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq K_n \subseteq \cdots \subseteq E$ such that $\mu(K_n) \uparrow \mu(E)$. This is the key ingredient for the proof that coincidence on compactly supported functions is enough. The other ingredient is a form of Urysohn's lemma. (Note also that compactness insures that if $\mu$ is a bounded measure, eg. a probability measure, then the integral over compactly supported functions exists, as their image is bounded by the theorem you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment above: (smooth) partitions of unity play a crucial role in differential topology and differential geometry. They let us make global certain local constructions, and in particular they can be used to prove the *Whitney Embedding Theorem,* one of the more famous results of smooth topology.

> **(Strong) Whitney Embedding Theorem:** Any $C^\infty$ manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ can be embedded in $\mathbf{R}^{2n}$.

Another important result that partitions of unity give us is the existence of Riemannian Metrics on smooth manifolds. Riemannian metrics are important because they let us generalize a lot of what we like about Euclidean Geometry to arbitrary manifolds $M$.

> **Existence of Riemannian Metric:** Every $C^\infty$ manifold $M$ admits a Riemannian metric $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contribution, I just want to mention that I am interested in their usage for point set topology, mostly.

Comment: Personally, I don't know of any huge uses of Partitions of Unity in pointset, but it might just be my lack of knowledge on the subject.